# How to work around Apex's case insensitivity?

Tags: apex

I have an apex class which iterates through a word and capitalises every first letter, however we can't use this on the name field in accounts because accounts with acronyms or initials get inappropriately cased.

I tried to add an if statement that determines if the whole word is already upper case, but it didn't work because through debug statements I found out that Apex was equating "test" and "TEST" as the same.

Does anyone have a workaround for this or is there a way of doing this that I'm missing?

```
public static String capitaliseFirstLetters(String name) 
{
    name = name.toLowerCase();
    String result = '';
    //List of separators after which we should capitalize letter
    String[] separatorList = new String[]{' ','-'};
    if (name != null && name != '') 
    {
        result = name;
        for(String separator : separatorList)
        {
            String tmpResult = '';
            for (String iter : result.split('[' + separator+']+')) 
            {        
                System.debug('Begin iter loop. tmpResult: ' + tmpResult + '. iter: ' + iter);         
                if (iter != null && iter != '') 
                {
                    System.debug('Iter: ' + iter + ' is not equal to null AND not blank.');
                    if (iter != iter.toUpperCase())
                    {
                        System.debug('Iter: ' + iter + ' is not equal to an upper case version of itself: ' + iter.toUpperCase() + '.');
                        if (iter.length() > 1 ) 
                        {   
                            System.debug('Iter is bigger than 1.');
                            tmpResult += iter.substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + iter.substring(1,iter.length()) + separator;
                        }
                        else 
                        {
                            System.debug('Iter is not bigger than 1.');
                            tmpResult += iter.substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + separator;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        System.debug('Iter: ' + iter + ' is equal to an upper case version of itself: ' + iter.toUpperCase() + '.');
                        tmpResult += iter + separator;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    System.debug('Iter is either equal to null or blank.');
                }
                System.debug('End iter loop. tmpResult: ' + tmpResult + '. iter: ' + iter);   
            }
            result = tmpResult.substring(0, tmpResult.length() - 1);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Related: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/80456/33673

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Can you use the String .equals method, as this is case sensitive

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/dbcom_apex250/Content/apex_methods_system_string.htm

```
String myString1 = 'Abc';
String myString2 = 'abc';
Boolean result = myString1.equals(myString2);
System.assertEquals(result, false);
```

Note that the == operator also performs String comparison, but is case-insensitive to match Apex semantics. (== is case-sensitive for ID comparison for the same reason.)

Comment: I found the reference for these string operations almost immediately after I posted the question but thank you. Also noticed that the function sets the whole word to lower case at the start anyway :/

Answer (score 2):

Try using [String methods](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/dbcom_apex250/Content/apex_methods_system_string.htm).

```
if (!iter.equals(iter.toUpperCase()))
```