# system.NullpointerException:Attempt to de-reference a null object

Tags: apex, trigger, lightning, developer-console, developer

I am getting error

**system.NullpointerException:Attempt to de-reference a null object**

It is working fine in sandbox once i deploy in production it gave me error as above.

```
set<String> unqName = new Set<String>();
List<Account> actLst = new List<Account>();
Map<String,List<Account>> act = new Map<String,List<Account>>(); // add list item to map

for(Account a:[SELECT Id,Name,duplicate__c FROM Account where Id In (Select Account_Name__c FROM Opportunity__c)])
{
    unqName.add(a.Name);
}

for(Account a:[SELECT Id,Name,duplicate__c FROM Account where Id In (Select AccountId FROM Contact)])
{
    unqName.add(a.Name);
}

List<AggregateResult> acc=[SELECT Name accname,  Prospect_Code__c  , COUNT(Id) ids FROM Account where Id Not
                           In (Select Account_Name__c FROM Opportunity__c) And Id Not In (Select AccountId FROM Contact)                           
                           GROUP BY Name, Prospect_Code__c  HAVING count(Id)>1];

List<Account> accList = [SELECT Id,Name,duplicate__c FROM Account where Id Not
                           In (Select AccountId from Contact) And Id Not In (Select Account_Name__c FROM Opportunity__c)];

for(Account acc : accList)
{
    if(!act.containsKey(acc.Name))
        {
            act.put(acc.Name,new List<Account>{acc});
        }
    else 
        {
            act.get(acc.Name).add(acc);
           // System.debug(act.get(acc.Name));
        }

}

System.debug('Name' + unqName);

for(String tmp : act.keySet()){
    for(String s:unqName){
        if(s!=tmp){
            for(Account a:act.get(tmp)){
                if(act.get(tmp).indexOf(a) != 0)
                {
                    a.duplicate__c = True;
                    actLst.add(a);
                }
            }
        }
        else{
            for(Account a:act.get(s)){         //error here....
                    a.duplicate__c = True;
                    actLst.add(a);
            }
        }
    }
}

System.debug(' actLst size '+ actLst.size());

        if(!actLst.isEmpty()){
            update accList;
            System.debug('accList size ' + actLst.size());
            System.debug('accList ' + actLst);
        }
```

Comment: Please [edit] to explain *where* you receive this exception.

Comment: done Please check

Comment: Welcome! I've answered your question, but please review [How to Ask](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve future questions here. More detail about what you've tried and where you are stuck would have been helpful here.

Answer (score 1):

The problem has to do with case sensitive vs. insensitive string equality.

TL;DR; use the current `act` key, `tmp`, rather than the current `unqName` value, `s` to get the map value:

```
        else{
            for(Account a:act.get(tmp)){
```

You hit the `else` when `s!=tmp` is false, ie, when `s == tmp` is true. From the answer and link at [this question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/80456/is-there-any-difference-in-equals-and-for-string-variables), we see that `==` is case-insensitive for Strings. But [Map keys that are strings](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_collections_maps.htm) **are** case sensitive. So 2 `Account.Name` values, `General Electric` and `gEneral eLectric`, would be `==`, but  `Map.get('General Electric')` will fail if there's only a map key `'gEneral eLectric'`.

Comment: Thanks @Thomas Taylor but i am getting       System.LimitException: Apex CPU time limit exceeded .....as i have more than 3000 records

Comment: Sorry to hear that. That's separate from your question, though. CPU timeouts are a whole different issue - you need to consider not just this code, but any triggers or declarative automation your updates may cause to run.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution using **APEX BATCH**

```
global class findDuplicateAccountBatchClass implements Database.Batchable<sObject>,  Database.Stateful {
    global set<String> unqName = new Set<String>();
    global List<Account> actLst = new List<Account>();
    global Map<String, List<Account>> act = new Map<String, List<Account>>();
    global map<id, account> accmap = new map<id, account>();

    global findDuplicateAccountBatchClass(){
        System.debug('In findDuplicateAccountBatchClass');
        for(Account a : [SELECT Id, Name, duplicate__c FROM Account where Id In (Select Account_Name__c FROM Opportunity__c)]){
            unqName.add(a.Name);
        }
        for(Account a : [SELECT Id,Name,duplicate__c FROM Account where Id In (Select AccountId FROM Contact)]){
            unqName.add(a.Name);
        }
        List<AggregateResult> acc = [SELECT Name accname,  Prospect_Code__c  , COUNT(Id) ids FROM Account where Id Not
                                   In (Select Account_Name__c FROM Opportunity__c) And Id Not In (Select AccountId FROM Contact)                           
                                   GROUP BY Name, Prospect_Code__c  HAVING count(Id)>1];
    }
    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
        String query = 'SELECT Id,Name,duplicate__c FROM Account where Id Not In (Select AccountId from Contact) And Id Not In (Select Account_Name__c FROM Opportunity__c)';    
        return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
    }
    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<sObject> scope){
        System.debug('In execute');
        for(sObject ss : scope)
        {
            Account acc = (Account)ss;
            System.debug('Account '+ acc.Id +' '+ acc.Name);
            if(!act.containsKey(acc.Name))
            {
                act.put(acc.Name, new List<Account>{acc});
            }
            else 
            {
                act.get(acc.Name).add(acc);
                // System.debug(act.get(acc.Name));
            }
        }
        System.debug('Name :' + unqName);
        for(String tmp : act.keySet()){
            for(String s : unqName){
                if(s!=tmp){
                    for(Account a : act.get(tmp)){
                        if(act.get(tmp).indexOf(a) != 0)
                        {
                            a.duplicate__c = True;
                            actLst.add(a);
                        }
                    }
                }
                else{
                    for(Account a : act.get(tmp)){
                        a.duplicate__c = True;
                        actLst.add(a);
                    }
                }
            }
        }    
        System.debug(' actLst size ' + actLst.size());
        accmap.putall(actLst);
        System.debug(' accmap size ' + accmap.size());
        if(accmap.size()>0){
            update accmap.values();
        }
        /*if(!actLst.isEmpty()){
            System.debug('accList size ' + actLst.size());
            update actLst;
            System.debug('accList size ' + actLst.size());
            System.debug('accList ' + actLst);
        }*/
    }
    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC){
    }
}
```

Run below code in console

```
findDuplicateAccountBatchClass obj = new findDuplicateAccountBatchClass();
Database.executeBatch(obj, 10);
```